# Spring @Async vs completable future run async

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous

I might have been doing something really wrong. So, I have Spring's `@Async`

Let's say I have this piece of code

```
@Async("poolbeanname") 
Function () {
     // some code 
}
```

I have one more, let's say I have this piece of code

```
@Async("poolbeanname") 
Function () {
     CompletableFuture.runAsync{ new Runnable ()...} 
}
```

Now with the second code I can see, some threads got spawned but the first approach doesn't seem to spawn more than one?

Comment: So, do you want to know why first approach create one thread and second one creates multiple?

Comment: yes , it should create more than one right ? @coder-croc

Comment: Can you show real code? did you enable async ?

Comment: yes it is enabled

Comment: Because there `runAsync` again creates threads... Basically it is pretty much useless what you do you run async code async with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable using `@Async` you should use [@EnableAsync](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async)

> Let’s start by enabling asynchronous processing with Java configuration – by simply adding the @EnableAsync to a configuration class:
>
> ```
> @Configuration
> @EnableAsync
> public class SpringAsyncConfig { ... }
> ```

And you must use a `public` method called from other class:

> @Async has two limitations:
>
> - it must be applied to public methods only
> - self-invocation – calling the async method from within the same class – won’t work

Comment: Note that those restrictions come because of how Spring normally implements advice (by proxy object); apply to all kinds of advice, not just `@Async`; and can usually be avoided by using AspectJ weaving.

Comment: self-invocation – calling the async method from within the same class – won’t work

This^ Totally forgot about it. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
@Async("poolbeanname") 
Function () {
}
```

The above snippet will execute asynchronously using a thread pool, if you have `@EnableAsync` in a configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
```

or

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
```

When asynchronous is enabled, spring will search for a custom taskExecutor or a executor bean, if it is not found it will default to its own taskExecutor.

Check your log for the line where it says `Initializing ExecutorService....`
Out of the box it says that it initialized `o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` which will give you a core pool size of 1 by default.

To override the executor one only has to add a factory method to a configuration class for the `Executor`.

```
@Bean
public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(50);
    //etc...
    return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
}
```

If the executor was overridden, it might be that a one thread pool size was specified or `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();` was used.

**CompletableFuture:**

The code `CompletableFuture.runAsync{ new Runnable ()}` will create a `CompletableFuture` instance and execute the code asynchronously (create a thread) every time it is called.

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future
  = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> "This is processed asynchronously");
```

Comment: should a method that has Async annotation above it, always return a completableFuture object? i read in some articles that it should, but Async is enough to start a new thread. Can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

As  @M.Deinum underlined in his comment, doing this:

```
@Async("poolbeanname") 
Function () {
  CompletableFuture.runAsync{ new Runnable ()...} 
}
```

Is useless unless you really need it, because: `@Async` sends the execution of your method in the `poolbeanname` thread pool and `CompletableFuture.runAsync{ new Runnable ()...}` will spawn new thread out of your `poolbeanname`.

You can simply do this:

```
@Async("poolbeanname") 
Function () {
  CompletableFuture.completedFuture( futureResult); 
}
```

Note that because of spring's object proxies, if you do this:

```
@Service
class YourService {

   callAsyncFunction(){
      function(); //@Async will not work here 
   }

   @Async("poolbeanname") 
   function () {
      CompletableFuture.completedFuture( futureResult);
    } 
}
```

But you can use this workaround by auto-injecting the bean.

```
@Service
class YourService {
   @Autowired
   @Lazy
   YourService  self;         

   callAsyncFunction(){
      self.function(); //@Async will work here 
   }

   @Async("poolbeanname") 
   function () {
      CompletableFuture.completedFuture( futureResult);
   } 
}
```

Comment: `CompletableFuture.runAsync{ new Runnable ()...} will spawn new thread out of your poolbeanname` -> this is wrong; this will spawn out of `Forkjoin.commonPool`

Comment: `Error creating bean with name 'applicationServiceImpl': Bean with name 'applicationServiceImpl' has been injected into other beans  [applicationServiceImpl] in its raw version as part of a circular reference `

-> Your workaround is not working.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `@Lazy` annotation. I edited the answer

Comment: @BOTJr. what's the result with the `@Lazy` annotation?

Comment: but what is the difference between ```CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> ...)``` and ```CompletableFuture.cimpletedFuture()``` ?